# RegExp para URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Buen día!
Tengo una expresión regular para obtener solo la parte que me interesa de una URL. 
Tengo 2 tipos de URL
https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path/page/login?execution=s3p1
https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path/page/login

Por ahora, he logrado con esta regexp  `".*\/(.*\/.+)"`
obtener: `page/login?execution=s3p1`

El tema es que necesito obtener solo esta parte : page/login. Una sola Regexp para ambos ejemplos. He probado alguna otra con la que obtengo lo que quiero, pero al probar con la URL sin `"?execution=s3p1"` no funciona al no encontrar ninguna interrogación.

Muchas gracias de antemano por toda la ayuda que puedan proporcionarme

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que quieres: ¿las últimas dos palabras separadas por un `/` de la URL?

Answer (score 2):

**Específicamente con regex:**

Yo lo haría usando algo como:

```
/\/(\w+)\/(\w+)(\?{1}.*)?$/
```

Eso significa:

```
\/        un slash
(\w+)     un texto (grupo de captura)
\/        otro slash 
(\w+)     otro texto (grupo de captura)
(\?{1}.*)? query string "?blabla" (grupo de captura,opcional)
$         fin de la cadena
```

El hecho de que haya un fin explícito de la cadena indica que no te va a tomar los conjuntos texto+slash+texto que hayan en medio, sino sólo los dos últimos.

Como la url puede tener query string o no tenerlo, todo el posible query string también es un grupo de captura. Esto significa:

- Sin query string, no existe el último grupo de captura, pero como está seguido de un `?` el tercer elemento capturado está vacío.
- Con query string, tiene que ser de la forma `?xxxxxx`.

Una estructura como esta te permitiría parsear una url que tenga (aunque no es válida) dos query string de la forma

```
 https://www.miurl.com/aaa/bbb?param=1/ccc/bbb/?param=2
```

Porque la primera ocurrencia del patrón `slash-texto-slash-texto-signo de interrogación-todo lo demás` ya satisface el criterio y una segunda ocurrencia no cambia el resultado (ni tampoco hay búsquedas recursivas)

```js
var expreg = /\/(\w+)\/(\w+)(\?{1}.*)?$/,
  url_con_qs = 'https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path/page1/login?execution=sp1',
  url_sin_qs = 'https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path2/page2/login',
  exec1 = expreg.exec(url_con_qs),
  exec2 = expreg.exec(url_sin_qs);

if (exec1) {
  console.log('url con qs',
    exec1.slice(1, 3).join('/'));
}

if (exec2) {
  console.log('url sin qs',
    exec2.slice(1, 3).join('/'));
}
```

Una iteración más elaborada podría ser soportar URLS que terminen con slash (opcional) o que soporten slash+query string. Probablemente no te interesa.

```
/\/(\w+)\/(\w+)(\/?|\/?\?{1}.*)$/
```

**Una manera más corta:**

Dado un string de la forma

```
 https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path2/page2/login?lalala
```

O bien sin query string:

```
 https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path2/page2/login
```

Podrías explotar por `?`, quedarte con la primera parte, explotarla por `/`, tomar los dos últimos valores, y unirlos con `/`

```js
var url_con_qs = 'https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path/page1/login?execution=sp1',
  url_sin_qs = 'https://www.miurl.com.co/path/path2/page2/login',
  ruta1 = url_con_qs.split('?')[0].split('/').slice(-2).join('/'),
  ruta2 = url_sin_qs.split('?')[0].split('/').slice(-2).join('/');

  console.log('url con qs', ruta1);
  console.log('url sin qs', ruta2);
```